# Endless scrolling using StaggeredLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try implement staggered RecyclerView. I create Abstract onScroll RecyclerView Like this :

```
@Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int grid_column_count = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(grid_column_count, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemsGrid[] = new int[grid_column_count];
        int firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItemsGrid)[0];


        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem ) >= totalItemCount
                && totalItemCount != 0) {
            onLoadingMore();
        }

    }


protected abstract void onLoadingMore();
```

and I implenting by MainActity

```
//===============    
recyclerview= (RecyclerView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
            grid_column_count = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count);
            mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(grid_column_count, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

//=====================

recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener(getActivity()) {

            @Override
            protected void onLoadingMore() {
                if ( isFinishLoadingAwal
                        && !isFinishMoreNews
                        && adapter.getItemCount()> 0) {
                    getMoreNewsFromServer();
                }
            }

        });
```

But I getting error in line :

```
firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItemsGrid)[0];
```

log :

```
Process: com.ad.kamardagang, PID: 23350
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v7.widget.OrientationHelper.getStartAfterPadding()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager$Span.findOneVisibleChild(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:2337)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager$Span.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:2313)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:826)
        at com.ad.kamardagang.utils.HidingScrollListener.onScrolled(HidingScrollListener.java:90)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:3674)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2824)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3011)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
```

so  how to fix it ? or any solution ?
sorry for my english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29292495/1318946

Comment: i have following from that, but i have getting error  ``firstVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);``

Comment: `findFirstVisibleItemPositions` is not provided by `StaggeredLayoutManager`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Endless scrolling using StaggeredLayoutManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079478/how-to-implement-endless-scrolling-using-staggeredlayoutmanager)

Comment: @AmayDiam Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @DeepakRathore sorry for late anwer, i use this library > https://github.com/vinaysshenoy/mugen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this [Mugen](https://github.com/vinaysshenoy/mugen) for endless scrolling for StaggeredGrid with RecyclerView.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItemsGrid)[0];` with

```
 firstVisibleItem  = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); and try.
```

Comment: getting error  ``java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager``

Comment: cannot resolve method ``findFirstVisibleItemPosition``