# How to implement endless scroll (pagination) in recyclerview with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, infinite-scroll, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

Hello there I have a `recyclerview` with images loaded from `firebase` I want to implement endless scroll but the issue I'm getting is with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and I have to use it I cant replace it with `grid-layout`

> Note:- I have seen other answers on this topic but the majority of
> answers are for `LinearLayoutManager` and some for `GridLayout` but there
> is only one answer I found for `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` which I don't
> know why it's not working for me

> If you want more references of the code please tell me I will update
> the question

**Profile_Fragment.java**

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    ImageView accountSettings = view.findViewById(R.id.account_Settings);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.snipet_profile);
    profilePhoto = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
    editProfileButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_button);
    uploadImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_profile);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_Profile);
    editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
        assert getFragmentManager() != null;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
        transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(edit_profile));
        transaction.commit();
    });
    uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        BottomSheet_Upload bottomSheetSettings = new BottomSheet_Upload();
        bottomSheetSettings.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetSettings.getTag());
    });
    accountSettings.setOnClickListener(
            v -> {
                BottomSheet_Settings bottomSheetSettings = new BottomSheet_Settings();
                bottomSheetSettings.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetSettings.getTag());
            }
    );
    postRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerViewProfile);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            staggeredGridLayoutManager // I have 3 rows
    );


    postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            visibleItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
            firstVisibleItems = staggeredGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
            if (firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {
                pastVisibleItems = firstVisibleItems[0];
            }

            if (loading) {
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    loading = false;
                    getData();
                    Log.d("tag", "LOAD NEXT ITEM");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    initImageLoader();
    setProfileImage();
    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
    postsAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mUploads);
    postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
    postsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Profile_Fragment.this);
    return view;
}

private void initImageLoader() {
    UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(getContext());
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
}

private void setProfileImage() {
    String imgUrl = "www.64.media.tumblr.com/1276b4edef49034af70bda14325385e3/d8872c747cafa206-96/s500x750/aa915fc49a84b5295f0cd44145d655b66eb906a6.jpg";
    UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imgUrl, profilePhoto, null, "https://");
}

private void getData() {
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    databaseEventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mUploads.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(upload).setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    mUploads.add(upload);


                }

            }

            //notify the adapter
            postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            loading = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            loading = true;
        }
    });
}
```

**Update 1**

The main question code is changed with the current answer and Added the adapter class as requested

**Problem**

After implementing the answer there are no errors but the images are not loading in so I have updated the main code with the added answer

**PostAdapter.java**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    public Context mcontext;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    /* ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout; */


    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mUploads = uploads;
        mcontext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_profile, parent, false);
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_profile, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        Shimmer shimmer = new Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder()
                .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
                .setBaseAlpha(1)
                .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
                .setHighlightAlpha(1)
                .setDropoff(50)
                .build();
        ShimmerDrawable shimmerDrawable = new ShimmerDrawable();
        shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer);
        Glide.with(mcontext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
                .centerCrop()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(View view);

        void onItemClick(int position);

        void onDeleteClick(int position);
    }

    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        ShapeableImageView imageView;

        PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    mListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");
            delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (item.getItemId() == 2) {
                        mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use this sample [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079478/how-to-implement-endless-scrolling-using-staggeredlayoutmanager)

Comment: @OmidZakeri this is the answer I have mentioned above which for me is not working and I figured out some errors after implementing that answer but then I don't know where I can put the getData(); method in it, in short it was a mess for me

Comment: @VasantRaval What is the problem you facing when implementing the solution given in the link?

Comment: @akhilnair Hello brother thanks for your reply I have added the problems that I'm facing for StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem you already have a solution.

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new 
   StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            staggeredGridLayoutManager // I have 3 rows
    );
```

For second problem:

```
postRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener({
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        visibleItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager .getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager .getItemCount();
        int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
        firstVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
        if(firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {
            pastVisibleItems = firstVisibleItems[0];
        }

        if (loading) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                loading = false;
                getData()
            }
        }
    }
 });
 ..........
 ..........
  private void getData() {
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    databaseEventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mUploads.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(upload).setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }
            }
            //notify the adapter
            postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            loading = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
           loading = true;
        }
    });
}
```

You might have to call the `getData()` initially in your `onCreate()` so that some data loads up on the screen and you have a scroll behavior.

Update:
The second parameter in a StaggeredGridLayoutManager is orientation so instead of `context` you have to pass orientation `StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried a method for initializing the StaggeredGridLayoutManager but there is an error please can you check my updated question

Comment: @VasantRaval I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i have implemented your updated answer there are no issues but the images are not showing up

Comment: If you found this answer helpful according to your mentioned problem then please accept it as it would be helpful for others in the community.

Comment: There might be some issue in how you are loading the image in the adapter.

Comment: before implementing this method the images are loading properly but obviously all the images are loaded at once in the adapter  as there is no pagination I have update the entier Profile_Fragment code with the current one please can u have look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238307/discussion-between-akhil-nair-and-vasant-raval).